# Can not send push messages from client

Tags: android, push-notification, parse-platform

I can send push message to a Parse.com client from Parse.com dashboard.
But when I try to send push from a client to another client it doesn't work and in Parse.com push panel it says :"No Alert"

```
ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
push.setChannel("default");
push.setMessage(msg2);
push.sendInBackground();
```

Comment: One thing to check is in your application's dashboard on Parse: go to Settings -> Push notifications and make sure you have Client push enabled? toggled to ON.